# Node.js line by line with async operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am attempting to read a stream line by line and for each line do some async processing. The issue I'm having is how to determine when the operations for all lines are complete. I thought I could use the readline "close" event but that seems to be triggered long before the async operations I've started on the "line" event complete.

Here's the event handlers in question:

```
logReader.on("line", inputLine => {
    self._processLogLine(inputLine, () => {
        if (self.streamFinished) {
            completionCallback(err);
        }
    });
});

logReader.on("close", () => {
    self.streamFinished = true;
});
```

The completionCallback method should be called when all line processing on the stream is done.

I've thought about adding counters for line operations started/completed and calling the completionCallback when they match but that seems awkward.

Comment: What is `logReader`?

Comment: `logReader` is the readline interface `let logReader = readline.createInterface(self.inputStream);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it basically keeping track of each lines success. I don't have enough of your code to test it...

```
const lineProcessing = [];

const doCompletion = () => {
  if (self.streamFinished && !lineProcessing.includes(false)) {
    // Not sure where 'err' comes from
    completionCallback(err);
  }
}

logReader.on("line", inputLine => {
  lineProcessing.push(false);
  let processingIndex = lineProcessing.length - 1;
  self._processLogLine(inputLine, () => {
    lineProcessing[processingIndex] = true;
    doCompletion();
  });
});

logReader.on("close", () => {
  self.streamFinished = true;
});
```

Comment: This is similar to what I wound up doing which was to use 2 counters linesStarted/linesCompleted and having my completion test be `self.streamFinished && self.linesCompleted === self.linesStarted`

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to tell for sure what needs to happen without more context. But here's a quick and somewhat dirty fix that should be adaptable to your situation. It shows how you can accomplish this with promises:

```
let promises = []

logReader.on("line", inputLine => {
    promises.push(new Promise(resolve => {
        self._processLogLine(inputLine, resolve)
    })
})

logReader.on("close", () => {
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(completionCallback)
})
```

Essentially, just create an array of promises. When you know that all promises have been added to the array, call [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on it.

If you use this approach, you'd probably want to add error checking ([rejecting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) and [catching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)).

Comment: This is a nice solution but I hadn't been using Promise's and not sure how much is involved in converting the code to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Look into generators.  They give you a way to do a "for" loop...and when  you're done, you just return from the generator function.

So you can have a generator to read the file, and a function that uses the generator, then when the loop ends, call your callback.